# Having trouble implementing draw instruction in chip8 emulator

Tags: c, emulation, chip-8

Hello everyone so basically im creating a chip8 emulator and im having a bit of trouble implementing the draw instruction. the chip 8 has a screen of 64x32 i have a array of size 32 of uint64_t. chip 8 uses a monochrome display where each bit is whether that pixel is on or off. so now I loop through that array to get that 64 bit row. Issue is I only want to xor the 8 bits corresponding to the xcordinate and after it. Not the whole 64 bit row just the xcordinate and the 7 bits after it with the sprite byte that I have.

This is my code so far for it.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++)
  {
    byte byte_to_draw = memory[registers->I + i];
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
      // 64 bit number each bit representing on or off
      uint64_t current_row = screen[register_value_y - i];

// I want to xor here
      
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is way too little infomation to help you. Please show your definitions. How do you store your sprite that you want to draw into that array? How are your bits mapped to coordinates? Which bit corresponds to coordinate x=0?

Comment: If your buffer and your sprite have same orientation, you only need to shift your 8bit sprite data into correct position and xor your 64bit line. Convert the 8 bit from the sprite to `uint64-t` first to avoid problems during shifting

Comment: Im trying your suggestion right now

Comment: a monochrome screen of 64x32 means either `long long screen[32]` or `long screen[64]`.  But you did not provide information about what you want

Comment: @alinsoar is uint64_t screen[32] so basically long long screen[32]

Comment: @lizardcoder yes, need details.

Answer (score 0):

try following changes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++) {
    byte byte_to_draw = memory[registers->I + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        // Calculate the x-coordinate for this pixel
        int x_coordinate = (register_value_x + j) % 64; // Wrap around if x exceeds 63

        // Get the current bit in the sprite
        byte sprite_bit = (byte_to_draw >> (7 - j)) & 0x1;

        // Get the current bit in the screen row
        uint64_t current_row = screen[register_value_y - i];

        // Perform XOR operation only for the specific bit
        if (sprite_bit == 1) {
            current_row ^= (uint64_t)1 << x_coordinate;
        }

        // Update the screen row with the modified value
        screen[register_value_y - i] = current_row;
    }
}
```

It mostly works . . . the code will XOR the sprite with the screen row for the specified x-coordinate and the 7 bits after it, which is the desired behavior for the Chip-8 draw instruction.